# Forming Json Format String

Tags: c#, string.format

I am using this method to form `json` string and this is working fine. But i can't handle this if it contains more properties. Is there any other better method than this?

```
string.Format("{0}{1}longUrl{1}:{1}{2}{1}{3}", "{", "\"", longUrl,"}");
```

The output is

```
{"longUrl":"http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/12835?api_key=2c50a994de5291887a4e062edd229a72"}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, a "better" way of doing this would be to use a Json library. If this is in the context of an Asp.Net website (in the latter versions), there is the [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library that is automatically referenced. If not, you can use Nuget to add a reference to your project or manually add it, whichever your prefer. You could then do:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { longUrl = longUrl });
```

Note that you can also just use `new { longUrl }` and the property name will be the same as your variable name.

Comment: It should be `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { longUrl = longUrl });` though :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library. You can create an entity class which you want to covert to JSON rather than using string formatter.

for e.g.

```
    public class Account
    {
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public bool Active { get; set; }
      public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
      public IList<string> Roles { get; set; } 
    }

Account account = new Account
  {
    Email = "james@example.com",
    Active = true,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Roles = new List<string>
      {
        "User",
        "Admin"
      }
  };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

## output:

```
// {
//   "Email": "james@example.com",
//   "Active": true,
//   "CreatedDate": "2013-01-20T00:00:00Z",
//   "Roles": [
//     "User",
//     "Admin"
//   ]
// }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could just use a JSON serializer such as [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). Failing that, you can simplify somewhat:

```
string.Format(@"{{""longUrl"":""{0}""}}", longUrl);
```

Comment: I believe it won't work. There are multiple { and } other than {0} and that's problematic for string.Format().

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json):

```
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new
        {
            longUrl = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/12835?api_key=2c50a994de5291887a4e062edd229a72",
            someOtherProeprty = 1
        };
        var s = new JsonSerializer();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var w = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            s.Serialize(w, d);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`
then do

```
 var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"longUrl","http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/12835?api_key=2c50a994de5291887a4e062edd229a72"},
                {"anotherUrl", "another Url"}
            };

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example to create the following JSON string

```
{
    "userId" : "121211-121112",
    "accountId": "xhd1121-kdkdj11"
}
```

use the following string interpolation and formating.

```
var jsonString = $@"{{
    "userId"": ""{user.Id},""
    ""accountId"": ""{account.Id}""
}}"';
```